# Weighted Minkowski distance for DBSCAN

Tags: clustering, python, scikit-learn, scipy, dbscan

I'm trying to make clustering of image's pixels with DBSCAN, using RGB values and pixel's coordinates as features. It works well with just RGB values as features, but I want pixels with the same color, but from different regions, to be considered as pixels from different clusters (Imagine 2 red circles on image - even though their pixels share the same color, they belong to different circles, so intuitively, there are 2 different clusters). But, adding coordinates to feautres worsens result.

I've decided, that using a weighted distance metric, where RGB color have higher weights and coordinates have lower, could be useful.But I can't figure out how to pass weights for selected metric (e.g., Minkowski) to **scikit-learn** implementation of **DBSCAN**, or, how to precompute distance matrix fast enough (e.g., with **scipy.spatial.distance.minkowski**, it takes too long for feature's matrix with size of (14000,5)).

Any ideas how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've figured it out. It can be done almost the same, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064632/weighted-distance-in-sklearn-knn). And it works much faster, than precomputation of distance matrix.

```
clstr = DBSCAN(eps=7,min_samples=14,metric='wminkowski',p=2,metric_params={"w":np.ones(len(X))})
```